# How can I get my JLabel to draw a space in java

Tags: java, swing, whitespace, jlabel

I want my `JLabel` to draw spaces but for some reason they don't get drawn. This is an example of something that the `JLabel` should draw, but it doesn't do so for some reason:

```
                 =========                    
                 ==========                   
                 ==========                   
                 ==========                  

                 =========                    
                  =======
```

Is there a way for it to do so? Not with borders but with `<html>` or `\n` or something else.
The code for the `JLabel` text:

```java
label.setText("<html>");
for (int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++) {
        char symbol = getSymbol(i,j,image);
        line += symbol;
        if (line.length() >= image.getWidth()) {
            label.setText(label.getText()+""+line+"<br>");
            line = "";
        } // end of if
        System.out.print(symbol);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
label.setText(label.getText()+"<br></html>");
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and post a [mcve]. What is the type of variable `image`? Is it a class that you wrote? If it is then post the code of that class. Otherwise people will just guess and suggest (which they have done already). After all, you are asking for help in debugging your code and the best way for me to debug your code is to be able to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you want to draw the following:

```
  x
 x
x
```

In plain HTML you can add `&nbsp;`-encoded spaces (non breaking spaces) or use preformatted text.

Example using encoded spaces:

```
String txt = "&nbsp;&nbsp;x<br>&nbsp;x<br>x";
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>" + txt + "</html>");
```

Example using preformatted text:

```
String txt = "  x\n x\nx";
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><pre>" + txt + "</pre></html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using the CSS **margin** property should also work:

```
myJLabel.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
myJLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

myJLabel.setText("<html><p style=margin-top:20>" +
                 "<p style=margin-left:100>First Line" +
                 "<p style=margin-left:100>Second Line" +
                 "<p style=margin-left:100>Third Line" +
                 "<p style=margin-left:100>=======" +
                 "<p style=margin-top:5>" +
                 "<p style=margin-left:100>Fourth Line" +
                 "<p style=margin-left:100>Fifth Line" +
                 "<p style=margin-left:100>Sixth Line");
```

Which in a JLabel, should produce something like this:

[image]

Perhaps place the `"<p style=margin-top:5>"` and `"<p style=margin-left:100>"` into String variables and work it in your `for` loop as you build your String for the JLabel.